# What's the normal force on a squishy ball on an inclined track?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics

In this article...

https://billiards.colostate.edu/physics/Domenech_AJP_87%20article.pdf

...which analyzes rolling friction on a rolling ball, the author claims that the normal force on a ball rolling down an incline is given by:

[image]

Where $R_b$ is the regular radius of the ball and $R_e$ is the effective radius of the ball, which is less than the regular radius since the ball squishes under its own weight.

But I don't understand. Why does the fact that the ball "squishes" as it rolls change the magnitude of the normal force?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at their Fig. 3. The normal forces are not directed orthogonally to the inclined plane. You might say that their vector sum is orthogonal to the inclined plane, but I guess the components tangential to the plane still affect the rolling friction in their first formula.

Comment: hmm that makes sense. They should've explained themselves better. Why would it end up being that ratio though, Rb/Re?

Comment: I also thought it maybe had something to do with the surfaces (of the ball or of the plane) behaving a bit like a spring? Since its deforming?

Comment: @JoshuaRonis : If there are two normal forces with absolute values $N_1$, as in figure 3, and both of them are directed at an angle $\phi$ from the normal to the inclined plane, then $mg=2 N_1 \cos \phi$ and $\cos\phi=R_e/R_b$.

Comment: @JoshuaRonis : "it maybe had something to do with the surfaces (of the ball or of the plane) behaving a bit like a spring? Since its deforming?" Well, you can regard the track on their figure 3 as a caricature of the deformation of the inclined plane by the weight of the ball.

Comment: Wait a sec...then why do they say $R_b/R_e$

Comment: @JoshuaRonis : Well, I probably made a mistake in my previous comment, I should have written $m g \cos\theta=2 N_1 \cos\phi$.

Comment: Okay, got you! I see now: 1. $mgcos(θ) = 2N_1cos(ϕ)$ 2.    $N_1 = Mgcos(θ)/2cos(ϕ)$   $N_1 = Mgcos(θ)/(2(R_e/R_b))$   $N_1 = R_bmgcos(θ) / 2R_e$. In conclusion, as you said the normal force not perpendicular to the undented plane still affect the rolling friction. They forgot the two on the denominator though, or I made a mistake somewhere...if you can figure that out that would be awesome, but its not its fine, I understand it well enough. Thanks!!

Comment: @JoshuaRonis : $N=2N_1$.

Comment: lol I'm a bafoon, glanced over it and wasn't paying attention. Thank you!